# Using node.js modules in requirejs browser with nodewebkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I am using nodewebkit so all node.js modules are usable in my application.

I am also using requirejs to manange my deps, so I have this setup:

index.html

```
<script data-main="loader" src="libs/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

loader.js

```
paths: {
  watchr:      'mymodule',
```

mymodule.js

```
define('watchr', ['util', 'fs', 'path', 'events']
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
"Uncaught Error: Script error for: util
"Uncaught Error: Script error for: fs
so on till events...
```

Comment: You'll probably need to create a shim that exports the objects.

Comment: I did try still no good.